# How to fix pod file listing in Xcode target

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

Recently I have added firebase through pods in my project.

Before installing pod I have only QA, UAT, PROD, DEV in my Xcode target.

After installing firebase through pod I have a duplication of pods-QA, pods-UAT, pods- PROD, pods- DEV and some files of Firebase along with QA, UAT, PROD, DEV

Could any one help me how to remove the duplicated pod targets.

[image: Screenshot]